# C language doesn't scan variable after reading string or char when int required

Tags: c, while-loop, switch-statement, scanf

C language doesn't scan variable after reading that variable as string(or char) instead of integer
But the most weird is that it is entering in infinite loop

```
int main( ){
    int answer;
    printf("Hello\n");

    while (answer != 3){
        scanf("%d",&answer);
        switch (answer) {
            case 3:
                break;
            default:{
                printf("Invalid input\nTry again\n\n");
                break;}
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To find how C language works and fix the problem

Comment: FYI you don't need a block around each `case` body.

Comment: Side note: `int answer; ... while (answer != 3){` The `answer` variable is uninitialized the first time.

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Comment: The problem is when I try to read string or char otherwise it runs correctly

Comment: start() don't use scanf()

Comment: You can try code by comment start() and showCenters()

Comment: What *does* `start()` use? The MRE means we don't have to keep asking questions.

Comment: if you read a number it works well

Comment: but when enter string it doesnt read my scanf and enter a infinite loop printing only case 3 code

Comment: [scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer) may explain the reason you're having trouble reading char or string variables. It isn't exactly clear what trouble you're having.

Comment: @Barmar: Re “FYI you don't need a block around each `case` body”: It is a useful practice for preventing identifiers declared in one `case` segment from polluting others, so it should not be discouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add one more statement under the label default to avoid an infinite loop when a non-number is entered

```
        default: {
            printf( "Invalid input\nTry again\n\n" );
            scanf( "%*[^\n]" );
            break; }
        }
```

If the user will try to interrupt the input you can also write

```
if ( scanf("%d",&answer) == EOF ) break;
```

to exit the while loop.

Pay attention to that the variable `answer` shall be initialized before the while loop.

Comment: But why it doesn't read my first scanf. It is only for my better understanding

Comment: @Mihai I have not understood what you mean by the first scanf. If you enter a non-number then it is stored in the input buffer and you need to skip it. Otherwise a next call of scanf will try to read that non-number with the same result and you will have an infinite loop.

Comment: Если ты разговариваешь на русском пожалуйста объясни почему при вводе строки просто перестает читать scanf. Тоесть объясни как именно происходит процесс для понимания.Еще раз спасибо за решение проблемы и если что не злись на мои тупые вопросы)

Comment: @Mihai Если вы ввели не число, то оно не читается и остается во входном буфере. Следующий вызов scanf снова сталкивается с этим не числом и не может его прочитать, и в результате получается бесконечный цикл.

Comment: Значи при втором scanf он опять читает из буфера и не может прочесть и вы просто создали scanf который может прочесть из буфера. Огромное вам спасибо